# how to loop through array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I its basic but I am new to javascript. I am trying to loop through the array and match the objects that == my key.

this is what i am using right now, it works but i am only matching the first object that matches, sometimes there will be multiple objects that match.

Here is what i have now

```
var chartSeries = chartService.getSeries();
var marker.options.subdivision.id = 1345
var matchingSeries = Enumerable.From(chartSeries).Where('x => x.id == "' + marker.options.subdivision.id + '"').ToArray();
   var series = {
        id: matchingSeries[0].id,
        name: matchingSeries[0].name,
        data: matchingSeries[0].data,
        lineWidth: 5
    };
```

I need to include a for loop to match all objects.

```
    var subIdSeries = [];
    var subId = marker.options.subdivision.id;
    var series = {
        id: matchingSeries[0].id,
        name: matchingSeries[0].name,
        data: matchingSeries[0].data,
        lineWidth: 5
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < chartSeries.length; i++) {

        if (subId == chartSeries.id) {
            push.subIdSeries(subId)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should it be `subIdSeries.push(subId)` instead of `push.subIdSeries(subId)`?

Comment: you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if (subId == chartSeries.id) {
    push.subIdSeries(subId)
}
```

to

```
if (subId == chartSeries[i].id) {
    subIdSeries.push(subId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the whole script, from what you have so far, I can suggest:

```
if (subId == chartSeries[i].id) {
    subIdSeries.push(subId)
}
```